# Proper data structure for private field - Inventory

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am working on an assignment that involves managing an inventory of products. Specifically, we're given an interface IProduct and IInventory to implement. Most of it is straightforward, but I've run into a design roadblock, and I'm wondering about best practices.

I have two choices for a backing field of my Inventory class: List or Dictionary (a custom class might be overkill). The assignment asks us to:

- Write a method allowing users to add Items to your Inventory.
- Disallow adding duplicate items (items with the same name).
- Implement Indexers (so that myInv[myItemName] should return the Item corresponding to myItemName)
- Write a method returning the list of items in alphabetical order by name.

Given these requirements, I was about to jump in and make the private field a dictionary, but then I saw the requirement:

- Write a method returning the list of items in the order they are added to the inventory.

I am wondering what the best course of action in this scenario would be. I'm juggling between two ideas:

1. Create two private backing fields, a list and a dictionary, but that seems unwieldy and inelegant.
2. Use a list, and jump through a few hoops for the first four requirements (like writing a loop for the indexers, and making a sorted copy later when asked for alphabetical order).

Which of the above actions should I take, or should I do something completely different?

Comment: Why not just keep a list, that'll be your insertion order. When it comes time to print sort use a LINQ query and order alphabetically.

Comment: We haven't gotten to LINQ yet, but it seems I can do something similar by returning a copy of a sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd implement it as a wrapper around a `List<InventoryItem>` (or whatever specific class represents the inventory item). Something like this:

```
public class Inventory {
    private List<InventoryItem> inner = new List<InventoryItem>();

    public void Add(InventoryItem item) {
        if (inner.Exists(x => x.Name == item.name)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate item");
        } else {
            inner.Add(item)
        }
    }

    public List<InventoryItem> OrderedByName() {
        return inner.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }

    public List<InventoryItem> OrderedByDate() {
        return inner;
    }

    public InventoryItem this[int i] {
        get {
            return inner[i]
        }
    }
}
```